# String Matches, Java

Tags: java, android, regex, string

I have a sort of a problem with this code:

```
String[] paragraph;
if(paragraph[searchKeyword_counter].matches("(.*)(\\b)"+"is"+"(\\b)(.*)")){
```

if i am not mistaken to use `.matches()` and search a particular character in a string i need a `.*` but what i want to happen is to search a character without matching it to another word.
For example `is` the keyword i am going to search I do not want it to match with words that contain `is` character like `ship, his, this`. so i used `\b` for boundary but the code above is not working for me.

Example:

```
String[] Content= {"is,","his","fish","ish","its","is"};
String keyword = "is";
for(int i=0;i<Content.length;i++){
    if(content[i].matches("(.*)(\\b)"+keyword+"(\\b)(.*)")){
         System.out.println("There are "+i+" is.");
    }
}
```

What i want to happen here is that it will only match with `is is,` but not with `his fish`. So `is` should match with `is, and is` meaning I want it to match even the character is beside a non-alphanumerical character and spaces.

**What is the problem with the code above?**

what if one of the content has a uppercase character example `IS` and it is compared with `is`, it will be unmatched. Correct my if i am wrong. **How to match a lower cased character to a upper cased character without changing the content of the source?**

Comment: Is paragraph[searchKeyword_counter] an instance of java.util.Pattern?

Comment: Can you give some text samples, with expected results?

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine, what is your problem?

Comment: matches() will match against the entire string. It is the equivalent of using ^ and $.

Answer (score 0):

```
String string = "...";
String word = "is";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b" + Pattern.quote(word) + "\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (m.find()) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Although the answer is not incorrect towards it's results, I disagree with it's current state: -Be it about the OP's issues, or this answer's code, no explanation is given whatsoever. -Also, I think that the code, although not incorrect, is not really suitable for the described intended purpose. --- To prevent misguidance to the community members with this or similar issues, I think a [-1] is in order until this answer is improved or removed.

Comment: @TheLima - I respect your opinion and you are welcome to put anything to your answer, even all your above ideas, however please do not spam my answer with sooooo chatty comments. I would appreciate if you remove all your above comments. I respect you, even your right to downvote me, but I like to my posts clear, if possible... Thank you, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

just add spaces like this:

suppose message equal your content string and pattern is your keyword

```
 if ((message).matches(".* " + pattern + " .*")||(message).matches("^" + pattern + " .*")
            ||(message).matches(".* " + pattern + "$")) {
```